# Is there any way I can view my old passwords?

Tags: password

I forgot my previous password on my Ubuntu system, so I found this guide on how to reset it using the GRUB menu. But now I really need the previous password for something else.

Is there any way I can figure out what my previous password was?

Comment: First, you need to have a _previous_ backup copy of the `/etc/shadow` file; and, second, by using a password cracker you may be able to recover your password. However, this would be something next to impossible, unless your password is something very short and simple!

Answer (score 5):

No. For security reasons, your login password is never saved as plain text on the system, so there is no way to retrieve it. Instead, a secure one-way hash of your password is stored, usually in `/etc/shadow`.

Whenever you try to log in, whatever you type at the password prompt is hashed in the same way and compared to the stored hash. If the hashed input is the same as the stored hash, you are granted access to the system.

Comment: And previous hashes are also not saved when you change your password. Some online services do this to prevent you from immediately changing back to the old password, but Unix doesn't.